# How keep PWA alive even though mobile screen lock or off?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to keep progressive web application running in background even though the mobile device turns screen lock or off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The application stops running as soon as the screen is locked or the device goes to sleep mode. If you want to run JavaScript code in the background, you can use Web Workers.

Comment: Many thanks. I build a web application using Angular 6. Does web workers work with Angular?

Comment: Web Workers are a browser API, so they work with any web application.

Comment: In my case, it is an Angular 6 web app project, I need it periodically send message to sever over https protocol without any interrupts from smartphone status ( screen off, lock etc...). It can be realised by running this app as a web worker?